How to parse Twitter API Response with Node.js
I'm developing a Node.js application that fetches data from the Twitter API. I'm using the https module to make HTTP requests and parsing the JSON response to extract the data. However, I'm encountering an issue where the application is unable to parse the Twitter API response.
const https = require('https');
require('dotenv').config();

const options = {
  hostname: 'api.twitter.com',
  path: '/labs/2/users/by/username/:username',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN}`,
  },
};

const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
  let data = '';

  response.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', () => {
    try {
      const userData = JSON.parse(data);
      const followerCount = userData.data.public_metrics.followers_count;
      console.log('Follower count:', followerCount);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error parsing response:', error);
    }
  });
});

request.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error('Error making request to Twitter API:', error);
});

request.end();

const express = require('express');
const apiRoutes = require('./routes/api.route'); // Import your API routes
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.use('/api', apiRoutes); 

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

Here is the link to repo: https://github.com/All1nol/omarBentoGrid/tree/master/backend
Even when i try to return json manually it doesn't return anything.But i got the api from official site, i dunno what's wrong with it.

Do you get anything when logging out each of the pieces?

@JoeLissner no, i don't

Have you confirmed you can hit your route?

So, Twitter Labs won't work anymore.
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users-by-username-username
This is up-to date one but it requires paid access tiers and it is 100$ per month.
